# Update property in collection with LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new to Linq.

My actual code is this

```
  Dim dt As DataTable = GetData()

  Dim listOrder = From a In dt _
                  Group a By key = a("Name") Into g = Group _
                  Select Id = key, TotPoints = g.Sum(Function(r)r("Points"))
                  Order By TotPoints Descending

  For Each item In listOrder 
      If item.Id = 1 Then
         item.TotPoints = CalculateNewPoints()
      End If
  Next
```

The problem is that when trying to update a property receive the message: The property "xxxx" is ReadOnly

Thanks for any help!! and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: check if the property for which you are getting this error is readonly or something?

Comment: What is the type of `lista`?

Comment: I'd guess that the fact your TotPoints field is an aggregate prevents it from  being updatable.

Comment: Sorry!!!!, lista.Id and Lista.TotPoints are item.Id and item.TotPoints

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be. I believe that `lista` is a typo and it should be `item`. Here `item` iterator inside foreach is a readonly object reference and using which you can't perform any write operation like the way you are trying. Rather use a `for` loop.

```
  For Each item In listOrder 
      If item.Id = 1 Then
         item.TotPoints = CalculateNewPoints()
      End If
```

You can as well use another LINQ query and then update the data like below but this would work only if `Id` is unique and there is only record with Id 1.

```
Itemtype item = listOrder.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
item.TotPoints = CalculateNewPoints();
```

Comment: Dim item = listOrder.Single(Function(r) r.Id = 1) item.TotPoints = CalculateNewPoints(), same error "The property "TotPoints" is ReadOnly"

Comment: @Chuckg, in that case check the property definition in your class. Look like that's getter only property. I mean no setter present.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating instances of an anonymous type `{ Id, TotPoints }`. Later on, you try to modify `TotPoints`. But anonymous types are immutable, or read-only, so you get this exception. The solution is to assign the right values at once:

```
Dim listOrder = From a In dt _
                Group a By key = a("Name") Into g = Group _
                Select _ 
                    Id = key, _
                    TotPoints = If (key = 1 _
                                    , CalculateNewPoints() _
                                    , g.Sum(Function(r)r("Points")))
                Order By TotPoints Descending
```